# Dagger - android.app.IntentService with @Inject

Tags: android, dagger

Is it possible to Inject object exposed through dagger into android.app.IntentService?
If so, how I can do that?

I want to have something like that.

```
public class SomeService extends android.app.IntentService {

@Inject
Synchronizer synchronizer;

public SomeService(String name) {
    super(name);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    synchronizer.doSynch();
}
```

}

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From a dagger point of view, `IntentService` isn't different from any other class.

However Dagger 2.x provides a new way, how you can inject dependencies into Android's base building element (like Service, Activities, Fragment etc.). Here sample calls for both versions.

**Dagger 1.x**

Injection can look like that (I'm assuming, that your Application has an instance of ObjectGraph and exposes method *inject*). Of course, don't forget add the class into a injected classes list in your *Module* definition.

```java
  public class SomeService extends android.app.IntentService {

   @Inject
   Synchronizer synchronizer;

   public SomeService(String name) {
     super(name);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     ((YourApplication) getApplication()).inject(this);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      synchronizer.doSynch();
   }
}
```

**Dagger 2.10+**

Dagger 2.10 has introduced `AndroidInjection` so no further dependency on the concrete Application instance is required.

```java
  public class SomeService extends android.app.IntentService {

   @Inject
   Synchronizer synchronizer;

   public SomeService(String name) {
     super(name);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     AndroidInjection.inject(this);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      synchronizer.doSynch();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is what I searched. You're right. I can add that you need invoke .inject method inside  onCreate() method. But whole idea works as charm.

Comment: You cant get application in constructor method. Only in onCreate.

Comment: `getApplication` can return `null` inside constructor. If so, you can override the `onCreate` method and inject your instance here.